# javascript scrollTop changing classes depending on position on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

I am trying to create a active state of the page navigation depending on where you are down the page.

this is what I have so far....

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scroll >= 0) {
    $(".nav1").addClass("active");
} else if (scroll >= 500) {
    $(".nav1").removeClass("active");
    $(".nav2").addClass("active");
} else {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
}});
```

but not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).scrollTop();` cannot be negative. So your code will always execute the first `if statement`. This one

```
 if scroll >= 0) {
    $(".nav1").addClass("active");
 }
```

The rest of your code will never be executed.

Try seperate your `if statements`.

```
if (scroll >= 0) {
    $(".nav1").addClass("active");
} 
if (scroll >= 500) {
    $(".nav1").removeClass("active");
    $(".nav2").addClass("active");
} else {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
}});
```